# Unable to find encoder for type stored in a Dataset. error in spite of providing the proper implicits

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset

I was testing some basic spark code where in I was converting a dataframe to dataset by reading from a datasource.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession


object RunnerTest {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("SparkSessionExample")
      .master("local[4]")
      .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "target/spark-warehouse")
      .getOrCreate
case class Characters(name: String, id: Int)
    import spark.implicits._
    val path = "examples/src/main/resources/Characters.csv"
    val peopleDS = spark.read.csv(path).as[Characters]
  }
}
```

This is way too simple code yet I am getting compilation error saying,

> Error:(42, 43) Unable to find encoder for type Characters. An implicit
>   Encoder[Characters] is needed to store Characters instances in a
>   Dataset. Primitive types (Int, String, etc) and Product types (case
>   classes) are supported by importing spark.implicits._  Support for
>   serializing other types will be added in future releases.
>       val peopleDS = spark.read.csv(path).as[Characters]

Am using Spark 2.4 and sbr 2.12.8 though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually the problem here was that the `case class` was inside the main `object`. For some reason spark doesn't like it.It was a silly mistake but took a while to figure out what was missing. Once I moved `case class` out of `object`,it just compiled fine.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

case class Characters(name: String, id: Int)

object RunnerTest {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("SparkSessionExample")
      .master("local[4]")
      .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "target/spark-warehouse")
      .getOrCreate
    import spark.implicits._
    val path = "examples/src/main/resources/Characters.csv"
    val peopleDS = spark.read.csv(path).as[Characters]
  }
}
```

Comment: I had this problem even after import spark.implicits._
Moving the case class definition to top helped solve the issue.